# How can I get a notification when the app is closed or killed in ionic?

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, uilocalnotification, foreground, localnotification

I am using ionic 5 and trying to get notifications when the app is closed from recent.

I have used local-notification also used foreground services but it's not working for me. How can I manage notifications from the background?

Comment: what plugin are you using to get notification? Need more details.

Comment: cordova-plugin-local-notification

Comment: want to show notification like other apps ,Like whats app , banking apps and other if any solution please suggest i did not found any solution for this

Comment: what Back end language are you using?
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm

Comment: Spring Boot , Without FCM can possible to run app in foreground always

Comment: what issue are you facing in location notification plugin?

Comment: It's Working fine when the app is foreground, But does not trigger is specific time or app in close from recent @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: local notification can only be triggered when app is in procces (not killed), else u need to do playaround to achieve what u need, u could integrate ur app with onesignal (which can also use schedules and anything u want) or firebase, or u can create ur own solution using native plugins to trigger ur app to work at specific timings such as "https://github.com/errietta/cordova-plugin-jobscheduler" for android and for sure there is same for ios if u search, or u need to create simple java & swift plugins to start ur app in background at specific time so by that local notification will work..

Comment: You need to write service to run something in background. Service can be written in Java/Kotlin only.

Comment: #2 i found a plugin for inoic too. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode